# Phoenix - compilation error when generating model migration

Tags: phoenix-framework

I am working my way through the guides on the Phoenix website, and I am up to the page on Ecto models - http://www.phoenixframework.org/docs/ecto-models - but I am getting an error that I am not sure how to address...

When I run `mix phoenix.gen.html User users name:string email:string bio:string number_of_pets:integer
* creating priv/repo/migrations/20150409213440_create_user.exs`, all of the files are created correctly:

```
* creating web/controllers/user_controller.ex
* creating web/templates/user/edit.html.eex
* creating web/templates/user/form.html.eex
* creating web/templates/user/index.html.eex
* creating web/templates/user/new.html.eex
* creating web/templates/user/show.html.eex
* creating web/views/user_view.ex
* creating test/controllers/user_controller_test.exs
* creating web/models/user.ex
* creating test/models/user_test.exs
* creating priv/repo/migrations/20161128174142_create_user.exs
```

but my server console immediately spits back an error:

```
Compiling 3 files (.ex)

== Compilation error on file web/views/user_view.ex ==
** (CompileError) web/views/user_view.ex:2: module TestApp_1.Web is not loaded and could not be found
(elixir) expanding macro: Kernel.use/2
web/views/user_view.ex:2: TestApp_1.UserView (module)
(elixir) lib/kernel/parallel_compiler.ex:117: anonymous fn/4 in Kernel.ParallelCompiler.spawn_compilers/1
```

And `mix ecto.migrate` fails, returning this error as well (despite adding the User resources to the routes).

This is actually my second time going through this process, and the first time I did it, everything worked just fine.  As far as I can tell, I did everything exactly the same this time (though I certainly may be mistaken).

I don't have enough experience with Phoenix to interpret this error or know how to fix the issue.  Can anyone help?

*** UPDATE ***
It turns out that issue came from the fact that my app module was named `TestApp1`, but there is a bug in Phoenix where underscores are inserted in names with trailing digits... so it was looking for `TestApp_1`.  I was able to fix this by simply going through the files that were generated and deleting the underscores.  See Dogbert's comment below for a more detailed description of the bug.

Comment: Which version of Phoenix are you on? What's the name of your application's module? (First line of `lib/your_app_name.ex`.)

Comment: @Dogbert The version is Phoenix v1.2.1, application module is named TestApp1.  Hmm, it seems the error is looking for TestApp_1. Perhaps that is the issue? If so, how did that underscore get in there?

Comment: Yep. It was a bug in Phoenix: https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/pull/1855.

Comment: @Dogbert I think this is the second time you've saved my skin - thanks friend! I ended up going through the error files and deleting the underscores - it worked! I wrongly assumed that Phoenix put those underscores in for good reason...

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that issue came from the fact that my app module was named TestApp1, but there is a bug in Phoenix where underscores are inserted in names with trailing digits when files are generated... so it was looking for TestApp_1. I was able to fix this by simply going through the files that were generated and deleting the underscores. See Dogbert's comment for a more detailed description of the bug.